# How to prevent the countdown counter from generating more than 1 value in the same second?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I'm generating the remaining value as seconds. If it is equal to or less than 100 milliseconds, I enter else and send a request to another function. There is a problem here, the counter generates more than one value under 1 millisecond and enters the else repeatedly. Or if I write the condition inside the else function under 1 second as a condition, it produces values ​​like 969,871,771 and enters else function repeatedly. How can I fix this?

```
function reset() {
        }
        function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
            var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
            return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            var remaining = 25000 - (Date.now() % 25000);
            if (remaining > 100) {
                document.getElementById("timer").innerText =
                    millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining);
            } else {
                tensecond();
            }
        }, 100);


function tensecond() {
            }
            function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
                var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
                return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
            }
            setInterval(function () {
                var remaining = 10000 - (Date.now() % 10000);
                if (remaining > 100) {
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerText =
                        millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining);
                } else {
                    reset();
                }
            }, 100);
```

Comment: Why does your interval run every 100ms? Set that to 1000ms and it'll run once per second.

Comment: Seems like this might be a case of [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you clarify what your objective is instead of asking about this specific part of this specific function?

Comment: my aim is this. I will have a counter and it will count backwards from 25. A 10 second counter will start each time this counter is reset. When this 10-second counter is reset, the 25-second counter will start again and there should be a cycle like this.@Domino

Comment: So can you explain why your interval is set for every 100ms? I don't understand how that related to your 10s counter or your 25s counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter(value, resetValue) {
  if (value === 0) counter(resetValue, resetValue === 10 ? 25 : 10);
  const use_this_value = value.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  setTimeout(() => counter(value--, resetValue), 1000);
}
```

see if this is helpful.